# I have given nested list accessing via for loop, but I can't getting result?

Tags: python, nested-lists, string-comparison, list-manipulation, string-iteration

```
patientsList=[['sagar','9856782311'],['mahsh','7865423158']]  
patient=['mahsh','7865423158']


search=input("Enter mobile number of patient to search")


  for i in patientsList:
        for j in patient:
            if search==patientsList[i][j]:
                print("required patient is")
                print(patient)
                print( "is Appointed")
                break
            else:
                print("Not appointed")
```

I need to check search element is present in list or not ,
but I can't compare the 'search' with list elements,
search is mobile number as input from user for searching

Comment: What's there in `patientsList`, `patient`, `search`?

Comment: Agree, hard to tell, if you do not provide the needed information, i.e. `patientList`

Comment: patientsList is list of patient,and patient list contains name of patient and mobile number of patient.search is element to be searched .

Comment: read doc on Python **for** loops, add dummy values of the variables, why loop over `patient`, why is `patient` not a class instance

Comment: @Shubham Try this: `for patient in patientsList: if search == patient[1]:`.

Comment: It is also not working

Comment: create a `Patient` class, better readability and maintainability. Using lists will bite you soon, and hard

Comment: `search` is not defined. If you just want to compare each patient in the list to the object `patient`, you should replace `search` with `j`: `if j==patientsList[i][1]`. This would be true for the second entry in the patient list.

Comment: see use a dictionary instead? basically you have to loop twice in the `patientList` because your list is 2 dimensional. Dictionary is more sensible here

Comment: your indentation is off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
patientsList = [['sagar','9856782311'],['mahsh','7865423158']]

search = input("Enter mobile number of patient to search: ")    

for patient in patientsList:
    '''
    patient looks like this ['sagar','9856782311']
    patient[0] is the name
    patient[1] is the phone number
    '''
    if search == patient[1]:
        print("Required patient is")
        print(patient)
        print("is Appointed")
        break
```

Comment: .It is directly going to else loop

Comment: @Shubham `else` loop? Smurphy you forgot the `break`

Comment: added ***break*** in the `if`

Comment: It is working only for first patient record,when I searched for second patient record , it goes to else loop

Comment: What do you mean? Are you wanting to be able to search multiple times, but the current solution only allows for one search?

Comment: What is your `else` doing? You should add that code to the question

Comment: Yes, I want multiple searching

Comment: If you want to search multiple times you will need to wrap that code in a while loop to continue until you want to exit. Also with the current solution, it will loop through all patients until we reach a true statement on the `if` thus `else` will be run each time it is false. If you do not want the statement to show up then drop the `else` or make it do something besides `print()`

Comment: Thank you ! Now by using while loops, problem is solved.Now code is running !